# Python workflow engine for multiple MapReduce steps

Tags: python, mapreduce, workflow, celery, pyramid

Fabulous people at SO,

I need to process a (bulky) set of data thru various steps; each step can involve mapReduce (using [Disco](http://discoproject.org/)), general distributed processing (using [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/)) or some simple processing on the server. I am searching for a workflow engine/library/framework that can help manage such a workflow.

I have looked into numerous options and [spiff workflow](https://github.com/knipknap/SpiffWorkflow/wiki) seems to be the most flexible but it doesn't seem to support actions on state transition and it's single threaded (so I am not sure how parallel gateways can be handled).

Please advise on the approach/tools to manage such workflow/jobs. If there is a framework that comes with a monitoring tool (preferably web based or can be integrated with [Pyramid](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/)) then even better.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This probably wont work for you, but you can do exactly this on appengine with appengine-pipeline https://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/ it depends on scheduled tasks which is roughly equivalent to celery. So at least there is the source that may inspire a hand rolled solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For pipelining batch data processing tasks, we use a solution based on great [Spotify's](https://www.spotify.com/) [Luigi framework](https://github.com/spotify/luigi). It's `central scheduler` scheduling and monitoring tool is a web server based on [Tornado](http://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/).